# Compiling dependency files: Linker Warning

Tags: makefile, make

I adapted a makefile to re-compile for changed header files by generating a list of dependencies.
The code framework already existed and all I had to do was adding a little bit of code for the compiling rules.
Now I get linker warnings. Which is confusing because when I compile my program, the linker links all object files which have changed.
Here is the part of the makefile that generates the dependencies and makes everything.

```
# Define Messages
MSG_LINKING = Linking:
MSG_COMPILING = Compiling:
MSG_ASSEMBLING = Assembling:
MSG_DEPENDENCY = Collecting dependencies for:
MSG_BINARY = Generate binary:

DEPENDENCY_RELATIVE = $(CSRC:.c=.d) $(CXXSRC:.cpp=.d)   
DEPENDENCIES_ABSOLUTE = $(addprefix $(DEPENDDIR)/, $(DEPENDENCY_RELATIVE))


CPPFLAGS = Some flags
CFLAGS += some flags

.PHONY: clean all
# building the binary
all: $(BUILDDIR)/$(BINARY_NAME).bin

clean:
    -rm -rf $(BUILDDIR)
    -rm -rf $(DEPENDDIR)

$(BUILDDIR)/$(BINARY_NAME).bin: $(BUILDDIR)/$(BINARY_NAME).elf
    @echo
    @echo $(MSG_BINARY)
    $(BIN) $< $@    

$(BUILDDIR)/$(BINARY_NAME).hex: $(BUILDDIR)/$(BINARY_NAME).elf
    $(HEX) $< $@

$(BUILDDIR)/$(BINARY_NAME).elf: $(addprefix $(BUILDDIR)/, $(OBJ))
    @echo
    @echo $(MSG_LINKING)
    $(CXX) -Wl,-L,$(BUILDDIR) -specs=nosys.specs $(MCU) -T linker.ld $(LIBS) -o $@ $^
 @echo $@ was generated.
# I added $(DEPENDDIR)/.%d ... to get the makefile to re-compile for changed headers
$(BUILDDIR)/%.o : %.cpp
$(BUILDDIR)/%.o : %.cpp $(DEPENDDIR)/%.d | $(DEPENDDIR) 
    @echo
    @echo $(MSG_COMPILING) $<
    @mkdir -p $(@D)
    $(CXX) $(CPPFLAGS) $(CXXFLAGS) -c -o $@ $^

# I added $(DEPENDDIR)/.%d ... to get the makefile to re-compile for changed headers
$(BUILDDIR)/%.o : %.c
$(BUILDDIR)/%.o : %.c $(DEPENDDIR)/%.d | $(DEPENDDIR)
    @echo
    @echo $(MSG_COMPILING) $<
    @mkdir -p $(@D)
    $(CC) $(CPPFLAGS) $(CFLAGS) -c -o $@ $^

# Dependency Handling

DEPFLAGS = -MM -MQ 

$(DEPENDDIR)/%.d: %.c 
    @echo
    @echo $(MSG_DEPENDENCY) $<
    @mkdir -p $(@D)
    @set -e; rm -f $@; \
    $(CC) $(DEPFLAGS) $(@:.d=.o) $(CPPFLAGS) $(CFLAGS) $< > $@.$$$$; \
    sed 's,\($*\)\.o[ :]*,\1.o $@ : ,g' < $@.$$$$ > $@; \
    rm -f $@.$$$$

$(DEPENDDIR)/%.d: %.cpp 
    @echo
    @echo $(MSG_DEPENDENCY) $<
    @mkdir -p $(@D)
    @set -e; rm -f $@; \
    $(CXX) $(DEPFLAGS) $(@:.d=.o) $(CPPFLAGS) $(CXXFLAGS) $< > $@.$$$$; \
    sed 's,\($*\)\.o[ :]*,\1.o $@ : ,g' < $@.$$$$ > $@; \
    rm -f $@.$$$$

ifneq ($(MAKECMDGOALS),clean)
include $(DEPENDENCIES_ABSOLUTE)
endif
```

When compiling, I get the following output. The code is working and the changes in the headers were included in the compiled and linked code, but I still get the linker error

```
wsl make -j16 all 

Collecting dependencies for: Service8.cpp
Collecting dependencies for: Service6.cpp
Collecting dependencies for: Service2.cpp
Collecting dependencies for: Factory.cpp
Compiling: Factory.cpp
# A lot of output and flags followed by
-c -o _build/Factory.o Factory.cpp _dependencies/Factory.d
Compiling: Service6.cpp
# A lot of output and flags followed by
-c -o _build/Service6.o Service6.cpp _dependencies/Service6.d
Compiling: Service2.cpp
# A lot of output and flags followed by
-c -o _build/Service2.o Service2.cpp _dependencies/Service2.d
Compiling: Service8.cpp
# A lot of output and flags followed by
-c -o _build/Service8.o Service8.cpp _dependencies/Service8.d
```

Linker warnings

```
arm-none-eabi-g++: warning: _dependencies/Service8.d: linker input file unused because linking not done
arm-none-eabi-g++: warning: _dependencies/Factory.d: linker input file unused because linking not done
arm-none-eabi-g++: warning: _dependencies/Service2.d: linker input file unused because linking not done
arm-none-eabi-g++: warning: _dependencies/Service6.d: linker input file unused because linking not done
```

And last of all the Linking Process

```
Linking:
# A lot of object files
_build/stm32h743zit6.elf was generated.

Generate binary:
arm-none-eabi-objcopy -O binary -S _build/stm32h743zit6.elf _build/stm32h743zit6.bin



23:00:54 Build Finished. 0 errors, 0 warnings. (took 4s.51ms)
```

So how can I get rid of this linker warning? Why are the dependency files classified as linker files? Is there any option to change that? I do not have al ot of experience with makefiles and am trying to learn the concepts, maybe you have some ideas how to make this code more efficient or clean?

Thanks a lot in advance !

Kind Regards,
R.

Comment: Okay, I by replaced  $(CC) $(CPPFLAGS) $(CFLAGS) -c -o $@ $^ in the compiling rule with $(CC) $(CPPFLAGS) $(CFLAGS) -c -o $@ $(<:.d = .cpp) or the .c equivalent. Everything still seems to work and the linker warnings are gone.